# Django: how to arrange products according to categories in admin page

Tags: django

In the admin page, I have two models: Category and Product.
When I open the Product model, I see the listing for individual products.

How can I sort the products according to the categories?

```
The "directory structure" of what I'm currently getting:

Categories (Model Root)
|
----Footwear
----Topwear

Products (Model Root)
|
----T-shirt
----Sneakers
----Jacket
----Boots



The "directory structure" of what I want to get:

Categories (Model Root)
|
----Footwear
----Topwear

Products (Model Root)
|
----Footwear
    |
    ----Sneakers
    ----Boots
----Topwear
    |
    ----T-shirt
    ----Jacket
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your models as show you below

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   class Meta:
    ordering = ['category']
    verbose_name = 'Category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
```

If you want to see all products for a specific category, you can try this

```
Class ProductInLine(admin.TabularInline): 
   """ Your code here """ 

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
   """ Your code here """ 
   inlines = [ProductInLine]
```

with this option, you can see all your products for a specific category

Comment: That just orders the products by categories. What I want to do is to create a folder and sort products according to their categories.

Comment: @DarkNRahlKarl can try with something like this:

`class ProductInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    """
    Your code here
    """

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Your code here
    """
    inlines = [ProductInLine]
`

whit this option you can see all your products for a specific category